# SUM AND LEFTJOIN SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I write this query

```
SELECT
    c.BID AS BID,
    c.BName AS BName,
    c.SName AS SName,
    CASE
       WHEN T.tHistoryValue1 = 1 THEN 'A'  
       WHEN T.tHistoryValue1 = 2 THEN 'B'
    END AS TType,
    COUNT(c.TID) AS TCount,
    MIN(c.TVaitTime) AS MinVTime,
    MAX(c.TVaitTime) AS MaxVTime,
    AVG(c.TVaitTime) AS AvVTime,
    MIN(c.TPTime) AS MinPTime,
    MAX(c.TPTime) AS MaxPTime,
    AVG(c.TPTime) AS AvPTime,
    AVG(CASE WHEN c.TPTime > 0 THEN c.TPTime ELSE 0 END) AS AvPTime, 
    result.ShowCount
FROM 
    c
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * 
     FROM cHistory 
     WHERE cHistoryTypeID = 4) AS T ON (T.TID = c.TID)
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN THistoryTypeId = 4 THEN 1 END) - 
            COUNT(CASE WHEN THistoryValue1 = 1 THEN 1 END) AS ShowCount 
     FROM tbl_THistory) AS result ON T.BID = c.BID
WHERE 
    c.TD = 0
GROUP BY 
    c.BName c.BID, c.SName, T.THistoryValue1, result.ShowCount
ORDER BY 
    c.BID, c.BName ASC
```

I get this error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
>   Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

What can I do?

Comment: If you comment out all the min,max,avg stuff, do you still get the error?

Comment: Can you please post the definitions of the tables?

Comment: The overflow error is probably coming from the second JOIN where there is a SUM being performed.  Try running that query on its own to see what happens.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is a good start when asking questions.

Comment: Learn to debug.  It's one of programmer jobs.  Have you tried to comment out all the aggregates, then uncomment one by one to see which  ones crashed your query????  If not, then do that.  Once you found, then figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Many SQL functions return an INT and have other versions to return a BIGINT. The [COUNT, for example, returns INT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql). Use [COUNT_BIG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-big-transact-sql) if you think your value will exceed the value of an INT. Check your other functions similarly.

[This is a good article on the NULL value](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/02/13/sql-server-warning-null-value-is-eliminated-by-an-aggregate-or-other-set-operation/).